# C++ constexpr vs macro in string literal vs integer

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, constexpr

I'm trying to figure out the difference "under the hood" between using a `constexpr` and a `preprocessor macro` to define integer and string literals.

```
#define FIRST_STRING "first_stringer"
constexpr char second_string[] = "second_stringer";

#define FIRST_INT 1234
constexpr int second_int = 12345;

int main () 
{       
    printf("%s\n", second_string);
    printf("%s\n", FIRST_STRING);

    printf("%d\n", FIRST_INT);
    printf("%d\n", second_int);
    return 0;
}

void hello() {
    printf("%s\n", second_string);
    printf("%s\n", FIRST_STRING);

    printf("%d\n", FIRST_INT);
    printf("%d\n", second_int);
}
```

which gives the following assembly output when compiled with `g++ -S main.cpp -std=c++11`

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "first_stringer"
.LC1:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $_ZL13second_string, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $1234, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $12345, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .globl  _Z5hellov
    .type   _Z5hellov, @function
_Z5hellov:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $_ZL13second_string, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $1234, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $12345, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   _Z5hellov, .-_Z5hellov
    .section    .rodata
    .align 16
    .type   _ZL13second_string, @object
    .size   _ZL13second_string, 16
_ZL13second_string:
    .string "second_stringer"
    .align 4
    .type   _ZL10second_int, @object
    .size   _ZL10second_int, 4
_ZL10second_int:
    .long   12345
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

On inspecting the assembly code, we can observe in both functions we have instructions `movl    $1234, %esi` and `movl    $12345, %esi`. I.e. there is no visible difference under the hood between a macro integer literal and a `constexp int`, even though the `constexpr int` is stored in a separate section `_ZL10second_int`

On the other hand, for string literals, we see that the instruction `movl    $_ZL13second_string, %edi` and `movl    $.LC0, %edi` map their respective string literal to two different sections.

What is the difference between these two sections? Do they map to different parts of main memory once the executable is loaded? If yes, is one part faster to access than the other? I know I can profile the performance impact, but I'd like to understand the theoretical reason and difference between these two sections.

Comment: If you use the string `#define` twice, you must rely on the compiler to de-duplicate the string literals, or executable space is wasted. The `constexpr` guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are functionally equivalent. Note that the actual data in both cases is declared using the `.string` directive. The only difference is in the label names, where the one which is actually a C++ object (`second_string`) has a mangled name, whereas the macro just has a generic label name.

If you run `objdump` on the executable in Linux, you'll note that both strings are stored in the `.rodata` section:

```
String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     4]  %s^J
  [     8]  first_stringer
  [    17]  %d^J
  [    20]  second_stringer
```

Answer (score 2):

A reason is that macro is handle by the preprocessor but a constexpr is handle by compiler. So a constexpr is not just a string substitution, it check types, for instance.

So even the assembly is the same, from my point of view, constexpr is a better choice